# Using Runtime to invoke cmd.exe and 'openssl enc'

Tags: java, windows, openssl

The following Java code executes a command prompt with OpenSSL started and respective arguments.

When I type in the exact code in the command prompt it works and creates the output file in my home directory. However, through my java app it just launches the cmd quickly and shuts down without creating the output file in my home directory.

```java
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();      
try {
    rt.exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe","/c","start  openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -nosalt " +
        "-in temp2.txt -out temp2.txt.enc -p -pass pass:QAAyADgAOAA9AEYAMAA6AEgANwBDAEIA"});

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try using full path names for temp2.txt and temp2.txt.enc?

Comment: Related, see [ProcessBuilder and running OpenSSL command which contains spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30433917).