# ProcessBuilder and running OpenSSL command which contains spaces

Tags: java, openssl

I am facing a problem while executing openSSL command using my jar in Ubuntu environemnt.
I have concluded that this is happening because of the space in the path of the file which is being passed as a parameter in the command e.g. SHA 256 in below command.
I have used both process and `ProcessBuilder` classes for executing the same:

***First***:

```
String certFilePath = "/home/mplusuer/Desktop/Nishant/210515/TestData/TestData/SHA 256/nishant.cer"
String []cmdGetAlgorithm = new String[3];

cmdGetAlgorithm[0] = "openssl x509 -in";
cmdGetAlgorithm[1] = certFilePath;
cmdGetAlgorithm[2] = "-noout -text -certopt no_subject,no_header,no_version,no_serial,no_validity,no_subject,no_issuer,no_pubkey,no_sigdump,no_aux,no_extensions";

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdGetAlgorithm[0], cmdGetAlgorithm[1],cmdGetAlgorithm[2]);
// setup other options ...

Process processGetAlgorithm = pb.start();
processGetAlgorithm.waitFor();
```

***Second***:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
String cmdGetAlgorithm = "openssl x509 -in "
        + certFilePAth
        + " -noout -text -certopt no_subject,no_header,no_version,no_serial,no_validity,no_subject,no_issuer,no_pubkey,no_sigdump,no_aux,no_extensions ";

Process processGetAlgorithm = runtime.exec(cmdGetAlgorithm);
```

the final command is as below, which works fine if executed separately on command prompt but fails when executed using java code:

```
openssl x509 -in /home/mplusuer/Desktop/Nishant/210515/TestData/TestData/SHA 256/suketu.cer  \
  -noout -text -certopt no_subject,no_header,no_version,no_serial,no_validity,no_subject, \
   no_issuer,no_pubkey,no_sigdump,no_aux,no_extensions
```

I have used the below methods also for resolving this issue, but nothing worked as per expectation:

```
String quoted = "\"" + certFilePath + "\"";
String escaped = certFilePath.replace(" ", "\\ ");
```

Please see to it and help me in resolving the same.

Comment: What happens with 1) ?

Comment: Please find the below errors for scenario :1) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "openssl x509 -in": error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)

Comment: Do you have a program called `openssl x509 -in`? If not, then why are you trying to run a program called `openssl x509 -in`? (As opposed to running a program called `openssl` with the first two arguments being `x509` and `-in`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java execute a command with a space in the pathname](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916918/java-execute-a-command-with-a-space-in-the-pathname)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> cmdGetAlgorithm[0] = "openssl x509 -in";
> ...
> ```

As @immibis stated in the comments, `arg[0]` is the program name. So the vector should look something like:

```
cmdArg[0] = "/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl";
cmdArg[1] = "x509";
cmdArg[2] = "-in";
cmdArg[3] = certFilePAth;
cmdArg[4] = "-noout"
cmdArg[5] = "-text";
cmdArg[6] = "-certopt";
cmdArg[7] = "no_subject,no_header,no_version,no_serial,no_validity," +
            "no_issuer,no_pubkey,no_sigdump,no_aux,no_extensions ";
```

You should always specify the complete filename of the executable to ensure you are running the intended executable, and not something planted by an adversary.

Comment: thanks everyone for your answers, i was able to execute it successfully.